# Add a search box to the primary nav

Tags: wordpress

I'm having some issues with trying to place a search box into my primary nav.

I'm using Wordpress 4.6 and this snippet of code is located within my functions file:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','search_box_function', 10, 2);
function search_box_function( $nav, $args ) {
    if( $args->menu == 'primary' )
        return $nav."<li class='menu-header-search'><form action='http://example.com/' id='searchform' method='get'><input type='text' name='s' id='s' placeholder='Search'></form></li>";

    return $nav;
}
```

However, it isn't working. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check this out http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58902/search-box-as-a-menu-item-in-the-nav-menu-output-by-wp-nav-menu

Comment: http://bavotasan.com/2011/adding-a-search-bar-to-the-nav-menu-in-wordpress/

Comment: Hey @user2584538, both of these solutions don't work for me :(

Comment: are you using custom theme or existing theme..? if it is a custom theme have you register your menu..?

Comment: I'm using a custom theme. I've registered my menu like so: 'register_nav_menus( array('primary' => esc_html__( 'Primary', 'cik' ),) );'

Comment: just try to add a  menu item without checking for menu 'Primary'

Comment: I tried the following code:

add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items','add_search_box', 10, 2 );
function add_search_box( $items, $args ) {
    $items .= '<li>' . get_search_form( false ) . '</li>';
    return $items;
}

And it didn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

Use `$args->menu->name` instead of `$args->menu`

Also watch out for capital P in 'Primary'

So a working solution will look something like this

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','search_box_function', 10, 2);
function search_box_function( $nav, $args ) {
    if( $args->menu->name == 'Primary' )
            return $nav."<li class='menu-header-search'><form action='http://example.com/' id='searchform' method='get'><input type='text' name='s' id='s' placeholder='Search'></form></li>";

    return $nav;
}
```

UPDATE - Registering menu

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'register_my_menu' );
function register_my_menu() {
  register_nav_menu( 'primary', __( 'Primary', 'cik' ) );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this still isn't working :( I tried Primary with both a capital P and a lowercase p. Still nothing. Am I declaring the menu wrong? My code is: register_nav_menus( array(
  'primary' => esc_html__( 'Primary', 'cik' ),
 ) );

Comment: Your code seems fine to me, which hook are you using to call this code?

Comment: Ah, maybe that's the issue, I'm actually just copying and pasting the code you provided above directly into my functions.php file, as it. Do I need to do something else as well?

Comment: The above code is fine. The only problem can be with calling register_nav_menus function.I am updating the answer by adding the code for registering the menu correctly.

Comment: OK, so I added both parts of the code (replacing my current method of registering the menu with your updated version) and I still can't get a search box to appear :(

Comment: I have tested the code myself and it's working. Make sure you have selected primary menu from backend

Comment: Just tried to add the menu in the backend, and it's alerting me of the following: Your theme does not natively support menus, but you can use them in sidebars by adding a “Custom Menu” widget on the Widgets screen.

Comment: Well, this seems to be very unreasonable. Try adding `add_theme_support( ‘menus’ ); ` in functions.php

Comment: That removed the error, but now I'm getting a blank space next to **Theme locations** :( Thanks so much for your help!